# "SAXParseException: must not start with xml" warning happens in some devices

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

i am tring to get an xml file from web server, and I have tried my code in some devices, some of them(Samsung galaxy i9000, inhon papilio g1) can parsing xml file exactly, BUT some(Sony Xperia z, Samsung Galaxy Tab3) will get weired warning and no result. The following are my code and the logs,

Code below:

```
HttpClient client = EasySSLSocketFactory.createMyHttpClient();
HttpGet methiod = new HttpGet(obj.toString());

HttpResponse response = client.execute(methiod);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

parsingXMLProcess(result);


private void parsingXMLProcess(String xmlfile) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource ins = new InputSource();
        ins.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlfile));
        Document doc = builder.parse(ins);

        Log.i(getStringFromDocument(doc));

        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("RequestId");
        NodeList nl2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("ResultCode");
        NodeList nl3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("ResultText");

        Log.d("check RequestId: \n" + getNodeFromNL(nl1) + "\n" +
              " ResultCode: \n" + getNodeFromNL(nl2) + "\n" + 
              " ResultText: \n" + getNodeFromNL(nl3));

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Log below:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: processing instructions must not start with xml (position:unknown @10:7 in java.io.StringReader@44802648) 
at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
at org.facetone.FacetoneFirstActivity.parsingXMLProcess(FacetoneFirstActivity.java:316)
at org.facetone.FacetoneFirstActivity.access$8(FacetoneFirstActivity.java:310)
at org.facetone.FacetoneFirstActivity$4.run(FacetoneFirstActivity.java:297)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I also did discarding the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, and the warning will change to "xml parse protocol not found", really have no clue to fixed it, any suggestion will be appreciated!!

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LicenseActivateRep>
    <RequestId>123456</RequestId>
    <ResultCode>1234</ResultCode>
    <ResultText>hello</ResultText>
</LicenseActivateRep>
```

Comment: can you please post xml response i think it might be xml validation issue?

Comment: @Haresh xml file added!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The construct  is an XML declaration, and can only appear at the start of your XML file.

The construct , where pi is any name that does not start with "xml", is a processing instruction, and can appear anywwhere except the start of your file.

So the error basically means that an XML declaration has been found somewhere other than the start of the file. Probably on line 10, column 7.

Why should you get the error on some devices and not others? Perhaps some are just not checking your XML carefully enough.

Comment: yup after printting out the result, i found some redunctant format appear before <?xml..., problem solved, thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
private void parsingXMLProcess(String xmlfile) {
try {
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     InputSource ins = new InputSource();
     ins.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlfile));
     Document doc = builder.parse(ins);

     Node nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("RequestId").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0);
     Node nl2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("ResultCode").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0);
     Node nl3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("ResultText").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0);

     System.out.print("RequestId  : "+nl1.getNodeValue());
     System.out.print("ResultCode : "+nl2.getNodeValue());
     System.out.print("ResultText : "+nl3.getNodeValue());

} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but the warning is happened on the line of "Document doc = builder.parse(ins);", Sorry for the belated information...